# Allowing insecure content in Chrome or Firefox not working, Google API Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https, google-cloud-endpoints

Trying to use Google's API Explorer to test Cloud Endpoints.

I get this error in console after seeing that nothing loads:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   '[https :// ] apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   '[http :// ]localhost:8080/*ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F*%2Fscs%2Fapps-s…3DEQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOS-9qNfJHxVBVUBVsRh4QjbpbBLw'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over
>   HTTPS.zk @
>   apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.CHA8zxoicJQ.O/m=client/…=1/am=EQ/rs=AGLTcCOS-9qNfJHxVBVUBVsRh4QjbpbBLw/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_0:159

I've tried the following suggestions, and they do not work:

1. In chrome, click on the shield in the upper right corner to 'load unsafe scripts' - now we are in http instead of https, but above error still shows
2. In firefox, click on the lock on the upper left to 'disable protection for now' - now in http as well but still no luck
3. Followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api Doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

Will try any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested again, and instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api) are indeed correct solution for Chrome. Make sure to enter the correct port.